# Mongodb: Fire post save hook based on a flag

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to execute some code in `post save` hook based on a flag that comes as a request query parameter. How can I read this variable in callback function? Can I somehow set it on the schema or the object where I can later refer?

```
var User = new Schema({...});

User.post('save', function(callback){
   if(someFlag){
      ......
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Any document have access to its *schema* through **schema** method so you could:

*router.js*

```
router
  .route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      var user = new User();
      user.schema.post('save', function() {
        var flag = req.query.flag;
        // ...
      });
      user.save();
    });
```

---

Or define it as a document method so every document has access to this method:

*model.js*

```
var User = new Schema({...});

User.methods.mySavePost = function(req, res) {
  this.schema.post('save', function() {
    var flag = req.query.flag;
    // ...
  });
}
```

and then in your router:

```
router
  .route('/')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      var user = new User();
      // register your post save hook
      user.mySavePost(req, res);
      user.save(function(err) {
        // this will call after your mySavePost method hook
      });
    })
```

Comment: I wish this was the right answer, we cannot call `mySavePost` for every request. for every `post` call a new hook is added to schema and all the hooks get called, with all historical req object